Doubt regarding Mint accounts
I am new to solana development. I was reading about how to create a mint account and mint tokens. I had a question that can a mint account mint 2 different types of tokens? like 2 different tokens like - 1. GOLD, 2.RUM

No, a mint account can only mint 1 type of token. But you can simply create 2 mint accounts for the 2 tokens. You should also check the metaplex metadata. So a mint is an account that can mint tokens, but you have to attach another metadata account to the mint, which contains the token name, symbol and link to json file that has even more info like image of the token.
